# How to make smooth transition lower and higher to flat

Tags: modeling

How to make this kind of transition?

[image: img]

From lower and higher to flat surface smooth without creasing or pinching? I triedy to merge the end but I get deformations.

[image: my model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is infallible, albeit extremely tedious: *the thorough study of topology*.

I'd recommend you start with [this blog](http://topologyguides.com/), a valuable resource.

For this specific situation, two basic rules apply.

- quads should be as square as possible
- quads should be evenly sized
- quads should be evenly distributed

Everything else will produce pinching, which you want but only at the sharp ridge. At that position I will use some rectangles.

[image]

[image]

Use a (shiny, reflective) matcap with lots of details for previewing.

My topology suggestion is not perfect, at extreme angles the reflections show the disturbance in the underlying structure. It should be improved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to move the Cursor to the top edge loop as shown here. Select the Edge Loop and press SHFT + "S" > Cursor to selected.

[image]

Then change to Pivot Point to 3D Cursor.

[image: Pivot Point]

Select the inner vertices and rotate.Press "R" and The axis to rotate on. Here it's "X". So "R" + "X".

[image: Rotate X]

Here it is with a Subsurf Modifier and Smooth Shading and some additional Edge Loops to tighten up the edges.

[image]